# Catching error conditions in Java Hashmap

Tags: java, dictionary

In an earlier question I was given some guidance on how to map characters to numbers.  In the code below I can use the Hashmap to attribute the number "2" to "a".

```
Integer number = characters.get(ch[r]);

Map<Character, Integer> characters = new HashMap<>();
characters.put('a', 2);
characters.put('b', 2);
characters.put('c', 2);
characters.put('d', 3);
characters.put('e', 3);
characters.put('f', 3);
```

Is it possible to code a catch all for the Hashmap so if say the character Z was entered I can catch this without the code crashing.  Basically I want to be able to code that if any character other than a-f is entered I can catch before crash.

Comment: If `ch[r]` is outside `a-f` range, it doesn't crash. You'll have `Integer number = null`. Note that it would crash if, instead of the first line, you would have `int number =  characters.get(ch[r]);`, because of unboxing failure for null value.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`getOrDefault`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) method to get a default value for any value that isn't between a and f:

```java
Integer number = characters.getOrDefault(userInput, 0 /* or some other default */);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a Java 8 [feature](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#getOrDefault-java.lang.Object-V-) to handle such cases :

```
characters.getOrDefault("Z", -1);
```

the value `-1` would represents unknown charcters not existing in your map.